# Ubuntu 19.04 restarts for no apparent reason

Tags: 19.04, reboot, logs

My Ubuntu machine restarted *while in sleep mode*. This has happened once before under similar circumstances, and I'm trying to narrow the cause down.

Checking the logs for an hour prior to the reboot I see:

`Jul 11 13:06:38 moz-Inspiron-7370 wpa_supplicant[1054]: wlp1s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with {MAC ADDRESS} [GTK=TKIP]`

a couple of these:

`Jul 11 13:05:01 moz-Inspiron-7370 CRON[12517]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)`

`Jul 11 13:05:01 moz-Inspiron-7370 CRON[12518]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)`

`Jul 11 13:05:01 moz-Inspiron-7370 CRON[12517]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root`

Which all seem normal so far ^

and finally:

`Jul 11 13:42:17 moz-Inspiron-7370 systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Succeeded.`

the last one runs about 5 mins prior to the reboot, could this be the culprit? Could it be doing some update and then an automatic restart?

After this the computer just reboots... Could there be any other possible cause for this?

Comment: This does not look like it is the trigger. Is this a laptop? Did you disable all the power saving options in your BIOS?

Comment: It is a laptop, and I have not touched the power saving options in the BIOS? how likely is it that this is the result of malware i.e. remotely executed

Comment: Rather unlikely the malware, really unlikely the remote execute, because in sleep mode the ports are powered out, unless set differently in the BIOS. What is the brand and model of the laptop?

Comment: It is a Dell Inspiron 13 7000. Could overheating be the issue? The fan has been turning on more often than usual and cpu usage is rather low.

Comment: It could, yes, but the fan should not be working at all while asleep.

Comment: Right, it ordinarily does not do that. If the fan is on in sleep mode, would you mind telling me what that could indicate?